# I can't find a way to change the canvas size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, web

I found this amazing code (props to the creator) online and I have been playing with it but I can't find how to change the canvas size. Like the width and length of it.

This is the Java that controls the canvas. How do I change the width/height?

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5/dat.gui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var glitcher = {
init: function () {
setTimeout((function () {

      this.canvas = document.getElementById( 'stage' );
      this.context = this.canvas.getContext( '2d' );

      this.initOptions();
      this.resize();
      this.tick();
}).bind(this), 100);
},
initOptions: function () {

    var gui = new dat.GUI(1),
            current = gui.addFolder('Current'),
            controls = gui.addFolder('Controls');


    this.width = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
    this.height = window.innerHeight;

    this.font = 'bold 12vw Arial';
this.context.font = this.font;
    this.text = "Bryan Chicas";
    this.textWidth = (this.context.measureText(this.text)).width;

    this.fps = 60;

    this.channel = 0; // 0 = red, 1 = green, 2 = blue
    this.compOp = 'lighter'; // CompositeOperation = lighter || darker || xor

    this.phase = 0.0;
    this.phaseStep = 0.05; //determines how often we will change channel and amplitude
    this.amplitude = 0.0;
    this.amplitudeBase  = 2.0;
    this.amplitudeRange = 2.0;
    this.alphaMin = 0.8;

    this.glitchAmplitude = 20.0;
    this.glitchThreshold = 0.9; 
    this.scanlineBase = 40;
    this.scanlineRange = 40;
    this.scanlineShift = 15;

    current.add(this, 'channel', 0, 2).listen();
    current.add(this, 'phase', 0, 1).listen();
    current.add(this, 'amplitude', 0, 5).listen();

    var text = controls.add(this, 'text');
    text.onChange((function (value) {
        this.textWidth = (this.context.measureText(this.text)).width;
    }).bind(this));
    controls.add(this, 'fps', 1, 60);
    controls.add(this, 'phaseStep', 0, 1);
    controls.add(this, 'alphaMin', 0, 1);
    controls.add(this, 'amplitudeBase', 0, 5);
    controls.add(this, 'amplitudeRange', 0, 5);
    controls.add(this, 'glitchAmplitude', 0, 100);
    controls.add(this, 'glitchThreshold', 0, 1);
    controls.open();
    // gui.add(fizzyText, 'noiseStrength', 0, 100).listen();

},
tick: function () {
    setTimeout((function () {

        this.phase += this.phaseStep;

        if( this.phase > 1 ) {
            this.phase     = 0.0;
            this.channel   = (this.channel === 2) ? 0 : this.channel + 1;
            this.amplitude = this.amplitudeBase + (this.amplitudeRange * Math.random());
        }

        this.render();
        this.tick();

    }).bind(this), 1000 / this.fps);
},
render: function () {
    var x0 = this.amplitude * Math.sin( (Math.PI * 2) * this.phase ) >> 0,
            x1, x2, x3;

    if( Math.random() >= this.glitchThreshold ) {
        x0 *= this.glitchAmplitude;
    }

    x1 = this.width - this.textWidth >> 1;
    x2 = x1 + x0;
    x3 = x1 - x0;

    this.context.clearRect( 0, 0, this.width, this.height );
    this.context.globalAlpha = this.alphaMin + ((1-this.alphaMin) * Math.random());

    switch( this.channel ) {
        case 0: this.renderChannels(x1, x2, x3); break;
        case 1: this.renderChannels(x2, x3, x1); break;
        case 2: this.renderChannels(x3, x1, x2); break;
    }

    this.renderScanline();
},
renderChannels: function (x1, x2, x3) {
this.context.font = this.font;
    this.context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
    this.context.fillText(this.text, x1, this.height/2);

    this.context.globalCompositeOperation = this.compOp;

    this.context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,255,0)";
    this.context.fillText(this.text, x2, this.height/2);
    this.context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,255)";
    this.context.fillText(this.text, x3, this.height/2);
},
renderScanline: function () {
    var y = this.height * Math.random() >> 0,
  o = this.context.getImageData( 0, y, this.width, 1 ),
  d = o.data,
  i = d.length,
  s = this.scanlineBase + this.scanlineRange * Math.random() >> 0,
  x = -this.scanlineShift + this.scanlineShift * 2 * Math.random() >> 0;

    while( i-- > 0 ) {
        d[i] += s;
    }

    this.context.putImageData( o, x, y );
},
resize: function () {
 if(this.canvas) {
        this.canvas.width = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
 }
}
};

glitcher.init();
window.onresize = glitcher.resize;
</script>
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript, please don't mix them up. :)

Comment: Ummmm... lines 21 and 22?

Comment: Thank you Licson, and Also Jim Garrison, how could i code it to a certain px?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp ?

Answer (score 0):

Modify theses lines:

```
this.width = 100; //document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
this.height = 500; //window.innerHeight;
```

with your values for the dimensions. If you want in this line:

```
this.font = 'bold 8vw Arial';
```

change the font family and size.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the width and height in the javascript code only? You can add width and height inside the canvas tag, like the following :

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="500">
```

Of course, these attributes can be written in the css file for the #canvas1 (in my example), you know. Anyway, try this and tell us if anything went okay.